# org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Timeout while receiving message

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:477) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:228) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:96) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:440) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:87) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:49) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.getMore(DefaultServerConnection.java:254) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:216) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:103) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:145) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.weihui.pythia.nestle.domainservice.provider.mongo.util.MongoUtil.getCodes(MongoUtil.java:151) ~[nestle-domainservice-provider-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.weihui.pythia.nestle.domainservice.provider.mongo.WareHouseCleanForPythiaService.updateIndexAndFundHistory(WareHouseCleanForPythiaService.java:98) ~[nestle-domainservice-provid
er-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.weihui.pythia.nestle.synchrodyne.schedule.wareHouse.WareHouseDataClearService.cleanIndexAndFundHistory(WareHouseDataClearService.java:55) [nestle-domainservice-synchrodyne-0.0.
1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:85) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

When I try again, it may succeed,it's not must.i think it's has nothing to do with timeout time,i set up 6000ms,that's enough

Comment: Every time I add a lot of data to mongodb,someone's size more than 100K to execute mongodb.insert

Comment: any solution you found for the same?